# error in custom list adapter class

Tags: android

I am trying to get server responce and store it in different string array but when i call adapter class till now it is fine but in adapter class will give me error.

```
    class viewticket extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pdialog = new ProgressDialog(UserLogedIn.this);
            pdialog.setMessage("Loading....");
            pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pdialog.setCancelable(false);
            pdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)  {
            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", u_id));


            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URLMyTicket, ServiceHandler.POST, param);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null)

            {
                try {

                    contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    int a=contacts.length();
                    Log.v(TAG,""+a);
                    String[] id = new String[contacts.length()];
                    String[] prob = new String[contacts.length()];
                    String[] desc = new String[contacts.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String aa = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String bb = c.getString(TAG_PROB);
                        String cc = c.getString(TAG_DESC);

                        Log.v(TAG, "TAG_ID" + aa);
                        Log.v(TAG,"TAGPROB"+bb);
                        Log.v(TAG,"TAGDESC"+cc);
                        id[i] = aa;
                        prob[i]=bb;
                        desc[i]=cc;
                        Log.v(TAG, "aaaaa" + id[i]);
                        Log.v(TAG,"bbbbb"+prob[i]);
                        Log.v(TAG,"ccc"+desc[i]);
                        Ticket_adapter adapter=new Ticket_adapter(this,id,prob,desc);
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  System.out.print("hiiiiiiiiiiii" );
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(jsonStr==null)
            {
               // Toast.makeText(UserLogedIn.this, "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String  result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            pdialog.hide();
            pdialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Now the problem in the adapter class that is it give me error at super() method 
    Ticket_adapter.java

```
    public class Ticket_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    UserLogedIn.viewticket context;
    String[] id;
    String[] prob;
    String[] desc;


    public Ticket_adapter(UserLogedIn.viewticket context, String[] id,String[] prob,String[] desc) {
        super(context, R.id.list_item,id);//error cannot resolve method super
        this.context=context;
        this.id=id;
        this.prob=prob;
        this.desc=desc;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, null, true);

        TextView idtxt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.uid);
        TextView probtxt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.prob);
        TextView desctxt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket);

        idtxt.setText(id[position]);
        probtxt.setText(prob[position]);
        desctxt.setText(desc[position]);


        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Error:

> Error:(21, 9) error: no suitable constructor found for
>   ArrayAdapter(UserLogedIn.viewticket,int,String[]) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable (argument
>   mismatch; UserLogedIn.viewticket cannot be converted to Context)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not
>   applicable (argument mismatch; UserLogedIn.viewticket cannot be
>   converted to Context) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; UserLogedIn.viewticket cannot be converted to
>   Context)

Comment: Error:(21, 9) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(UserLogedIn.viewticket,int,String[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; UserLogedIn.viewticket cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; UserLogedIn.viewticket cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; UserLogedIn.viewticket cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: The constructor of ArrayAdapter needs Context as first parameter. So, you can override AsyncTask constructor, pass context to your viewticket there, and then use that context to init Ticket_adapter. You can pass your activity as a context (Activity extends Context class), if you are using viewticket from an activity.

Comment: extends `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: there is no default constructor for ArrayAdapter that accepts the arguments you gave, as @Blackbelt said, use BaseAdapter

Comment: I know that. @AmanGrover.

Comment: Refer here to this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21859407/2713414 for the super implementation

Comment: if ticket is not present it give following error

Comment: Process: com.example.surun.suruninfocore, PID: 4994
    java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
            at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
            at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
            at com.example.surun.suruninfocore.Ticket_adapter.<init>(Ticket_adapter.java:21)

Answer (score 0):

Well problem is your invoking Adpater in for loop itself

Try this

```
 String[] id = new String[contacts.length()];
                String[] prob = new String[contacts.length()];
                String[] desc = new String[contacts.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String aa = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String bb = c.getString(TAG_PROB);
                    String cc = c.getString(TAG_DESC);

                    Log.v(TAG, "TAG_ID" + aa);
                    Log.v(TAG,"TAGPROB"+bb);
                    Log.v(TAG,"TAGDESC"+cc);
                    id[i] = aa;
                    prob[i]=bb;
                    desc[i]=cc;
                    Log.v(TAG, "aaaaa" + id[i]);
                    Log.v(TAG,"bbbbb"+prob[i]);
                    Log.v(TAG,"ccc"+desc[i]);

                }//for loop ends

               if(id.length>0)
               {
                Ticket_adapter adapter=new Ticket_adapter(this,id,prob,desc);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
               }
               else
                {
                  //toast which displays no tickets found
                }
```

Comment: what code is required there to handle if there is no ticket

Comment: if ticket is not present server send following responce status:failed msg:No  ticket present.at that time how to handle that situation

Comment: Process: com.example.surun.suruninfocore, PID: 18107
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
            at com.example.surun.suruninfocore.UserLogedIn$viewticket.onPostExecute(UserLogedIn.java:784)
            at com.example.surun.suruninfocore.UserLogedIn$viewticket.onPostExecute(UserLogedIn.java:719)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You need to create your adapter outside the `for` loop.

**2)** If you want to call `super()` in your custom adapter constructor, you need to pass a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) not an object named context.

Because from the error, `UserLogedIn.viewticket` is not a `Context`.

Take a look at the official documentation, to know how the [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) constructor should be (section *Public Constructors*).